# set up custom route for dynamic link, without using firebase hosing

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

According to the firebase official documentation, to set up a custom route like `/link` in your custom domain like `example.com`, I need to use firebase hosting already and do the following configuration there:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...
  "appAssociation": "AUTO",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/link/**",
      "dynamicLinks": true
    },
  ]
}
```

But I'm not using firebase hosting, and Obviously, I don't have such a configuration.
So I can have the same result with no firebase hosting?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past with custom domain names for dynamic links: when you get the error in the dynamic links page, open the Authentication(you don't actually need to use firebase authentication on this project for this to work), go to sign in method, enable Email/Password then scroll down to Authorized Domains and add your domain as an authorized domain. This won't affect your current website or email. Go back to hosting and try to set up the URL prefix again.

Comment: It's not related to Authentication at all

Comment: It doesn't need to be related to authentication. You don't even need to use authentication or have the SDK installed. Following these steps won't change or edit your site in any way.